# Flutter: Variable type widget push

Tags: flutter

I have such a piece of code:

```
class RenderCards {

Widget renderCard() {
Widget card;
for (int i = 2; i > 0; i--) {
  card = Card(
    elevation: 4.0,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[ 
        Image.network(
          "http://192.168.0.100/news_${i}.jpeg",
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
          height: 480.0,
          width: 320.0,
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
return card;
}

}
```

Can I add more elements of type Card to the variable ?
Or how can I do better to draw cards depending on their number, and not duplicate the code?

Comment: Can please explain what do you want to do exactly? I am not able to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class RenderCards {

List<Widget> renderCard() {
List<Widget> card = [];
for (int i = 2; i > 0; i--) {
card.add( Card(
elevation: 4.0,
shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
child: Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[ 
    Image.network(
      "http://192.168.0.100/news_${i}.jpeg",
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
      height: 480.0,
      width: 320.0,
    )
  ],
),
));
}return card;}}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I have images on the server, they needed to be displayed in the application. I was looking for the best solution